# React: data disappears on page reload

Tags: reactjs

I'm fetching answers from the Nest backend and displaying them. They render fine when I've just made changes to my code but then if I reload the page, they disappear. How can I resolve this?

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/...")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setQuestionsData(data))
  }, []);

useEffect(() => {
    setAnswers(questionsData.map((q: { answers: any; }) => q.answers));

    answers.forEach(function (answer: any) {
     const eachAnswer = answer
      eachAnswer.map((a: any) => setAnswer(a.answer))
    });

  }, [questionsData]);

const onChangeCheckbox = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    let isChecked = e.target.checked;
    setIsChecked(!isChecked)
    isChecked && setAnswerSelected(e.target.value)
  }

return (
<input type="checkbox" value={answer} onChange={(e) => onChangeCheckbox(e)} />{answer}
      <input type="checkbox" value={answer} onChange={(e) => onChangeCheckbox(e)} />{answer}
)
```

Answer (score 1):

`fetch()` is asynchronous, and thus, whenever the page reloads, the component re-renders. While the `fetch` function is running, the component renders *without* the data, causing your problem. Simply use a condition to handle cases where the data is loaded like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetch("/...")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => setQuestionsData(data));
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  if (questionsData.length > 0) {
    const allAnswers = questionsData.map((q: { answers: any }) => q.answers);
    const mergedAnswers = [].concat.apply([], allAnswers);
    setAnswers(mergedAnswers);
  }
}, [questionsData]);

const onChangeCheckbox = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  let isChecked = e.target.checked;
  setIsChecked(!isChecked);
  isChecked && setAnswerSelected(e.target.value);
};

return (
  <div>
    {answers.length > 0 ? (
      answers.map((answer: any) => (
        <div key={answer.id}>
          <input type="checkbox" value={answer.answer} onChange={(e) => onChangeCheckbox(e)} />
          {answer.answer}
        </div>
      ))
    ) : (
      <div>Loading answers...</div>
    )}
  </div>
);
```

These changes will also make your code run faster.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This has definitely helped to loop through the answers better however `answers` is becoming undefined when I reload the page therefore `answers.length` causes the error 'cannot read properties of undefined'.  @ichang3765